# How can I access the notebook camera from firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

I really need my addon can access the notebook camera if it does exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access the webcam in Firefox (and more generally in supporting browsers), you should use [`navigator.getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/navigator.getUserMedia)

> Prompts the user for permission to use a media device such as a camera or microphone. If the user provides permission, the successCallback is invoked on the calling application with a LocalMediaStream object as its argument.

[Here is a tutorial on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/taking_webcam_photos) about taking webcam photos.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad this worked out for you, the technology is very new and exciting :) Ever since http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsAWR_rJ5n8 was released it seems like it got more popular. Good luck!